# upload file using ajax temporary save in table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

In my project I insert data like files and other info using ajax, for the saving of the file I want to insert as many files so what I did is I have this table where i store the file content as

```
var file = $('#file')[0].files[0];
//var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
var name = file.name;
var size = file.size;
var type = file.type;
var newname = $('#filename').val();
var newRow = "<tr>" +
    "<td id=''>" + file.name + "</td>" +
    "<td id=''>" + file.size + "</td>" +
    "<td id=''>" + file.type + "</td>" +
    "<td id=''>" + newname + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + "<a href='#' id='" + id + "' class='deletefile'>Delete</a>" + "</td>" +
    "</tr>";
$("#filetable > tbody > tr:last").after(newRow);
```

This is how i save the file content in table so that i can insert many files in the database also this allows me to rename the file by using the `newname`.

after this I `push` the content of this table in a variable(I didnt include in `push` how I got the data from the table because it is too long). Then i put the variable in a formdata

```
$('#Addtotable').click(function() {
        var $rows = $('#filetable').find("tr:not(:eq(0))");
        var valueToPush = [];
        $rows.each(function() {
            var $tds = $(this).find('td');
            var nameoffile = $tds.eq(0).text();
            var size = $tds.eq(1).text();
            var type = $tds.eq(2).text();
            var filename = $tds.eq(3).text();
            valueToPush.push({
                nameoffile: nameoffile,
                size: size,
                filename: filename,
                type: type

            });
        });
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', JSON.stringify(valueToPush));
```

Note. I only included the append data for the file

the ajax then will look like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../include/Add.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
    contentType: false, // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //alert(data.message);
        //window.location.reload(true);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //alert("Error!"); // Optional
        //window.location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

and in my php I have this condition

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
```

My question is why is my `$_FILES` always empty when i try to echo the variable `($_POST['file'])` it will return the `correct content of the file` like the `current file name`, `file size` and `file type`

Comment: Show us the part where you are reading the actual file contents and add that to your FormData object.

Comment: this is all i have what do you mean by add the actual file?I add the entire table to the formdata.the actual file file is the row of the table and that table is in the `variableToPush`.

Comment: What is `valueToPush` then? You are only showing us how you are pushing an object containing the meta data of the file (name, size, etc.) to that variable – but where do you read the actual content of the file? _“I add the entire table to the formdata”_ – well if that includes getting the file’s content, then _show us_.

Comment: i have included the entire adding of table in now.That is how i get the content of the file. And also if i didnt mention from the php if I try to echo the variable file it will return to my ajax the correct content of the file, like `name of file`, `size of file` and `type of file`

Comment: _“That is how i get the content of the file”_ – no, you don’t – that’s the _point_. You should go read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Just a though this is from response in the `Network>XHR>Response` i get `[{\"nameoffile\":\"left.png\",\"size\":\"1312\",\"filename\":\"a\",\"type\":\"image\/png\"}]"{"error":true,"message":"Add failed!."}` the error message will show because the condition is `if (!empty($_FILES)) {}else{echo json_encode(array(
        'error' => true,
        'message' => "Add failed!."
    ));}` from the response i am assuming the the file content is passed to the php file the problem is the condition is not met

Comment: The condition is not met, because you did not send the actual file.

Comment: Ok i think i get a clear picture the only thing i send are file names file size and file type. Any suggestion on how to send the file in my case?i read the link you gave me and it is only applicable to sending one i already made something like that this one is a bit different.

Comment: No, it is not applicable to sending just one. Anyway, if you have built a proper form that would work the way you want it to if you submitted normally, without AJAX – then you can just pass the reference to the form element to `FormData`, and it will handle the whole thing for you on its own …

Comment: So the problem here is after clicking the `addtotable` the actual file was not saved in the table but only the file name file size and file type?i am guessing this is the case?any idea on how to save the file content on table?i was searching for sample and it leads me back here on my own post

Comment: As if that’s not what I have been telling you all along … and right there is an example, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects#Creating_a_FormData_object_from_scratch – now what more do you want/need?

Comment: sorry english is not my first tongue so i much have misunderstood what you mean or i didnt understand you at all.. Now that i now the problem maybe i can work on it for the mean time. You could provide assistance later if you are willing if i got stuck again :)

Comment: I tried putting the `var file` and the console logs it like `[object File]` is this the actual file now?i still get the same error.

Comment: The console will not try to actually display the contents. That message says that file has a value of type File. It could still be empty, but that output is correct.

Comment: it does show the content of the file i mean it is not only [object File] it is showing the breakdown data.i just saw it a few minutes a ago