# Store file content in a table(html table tr td) jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, blob

I wanted to insert multiple files in database by uploading/adding the each file content to a table then after adding all files to the table i add the tables' value including the file content in a form data which i pass to ajax. I tried

```
var file = $('#file')[0].files[0];
//var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
var name = file.name;
var size = file.size;
var type = file.type;
var blob = new Blob([file], {
    type: "application/octet-binary"
});
var filecontent = blob;
```

`Here i used the value of filecontent to be passed to ajax but in php the condition if(!empty($_FILES) remaind false)`

and on console.log filecontent looks like `[object Blob]` i want to do to achieve my primary goal which is to store to database i already asked a question about it. I can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29178712/upload-file-using-ajax-temporary-save-in-table) this is the problem why i asked the first one.

My question is How to store file content to a variable in this case store the value of `$('#file')[0].files[0]` to `file`.

`UPDATE`

When i used the value of `var file = $('#file')[0].files[0];` i still get the same error

`UPDATE`

Is it possible to store the `input:file` into `table td` or `input` or `any other element` and reuse that file if needed

Answer (score 0):

To store content of a file into a variable you first need to read them , so you will have to use a **[FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)**.

For example `readAsText()` method Syntax:

```
instanceOfFileReader.readAsText(blob[, encoding]);
```

> The readAsText method is used to read the contents of the specified
>   Blob or File. When the read operation is complete, the readyState is
>   changed to DONE, the loadend is triggered, and the result attribute
>   contains the contents of the file as a text string.

Hence you can store the result to your variable.

Comment: i was able to store it to variable what about storing to a td of table or anything that i can reuse to get the content back for ajax request i want to achieve this because of my other question.

Comment: @Pekka you mean like reverse engineering ? and a td of table can store data as text or html-data so please be specific.

Comment: what i mean is from the input type file i want to store the data(of the input file) temporarily in a table in td because i want to insert to database more and i want to show the user what data are available for insert to database. also this way i can be able to rename the file before storing it in database. I want to know if it is possible to store the file content not only the information such as filename filesize and filetype but the file itself

Comment: @Pekka suppose your file is 50 mb movie how do you think you can store this as raw data ? the file itself needs a storage , have you checked filereader api methods ?

Comment: actually im limiting the files to only pdf,images(although i havent had any idea how).because in my design for my project my goal is to save multiple files rename those files if possible so the only way i can think of this design.as much as possible i want jquery only

Comment: @Pekka can you please describe the exact issue so i can help , so let me get this clear . you want to store images and pdf files uploaded by user , and insert files themselves into database ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73468/discussion-between-pekka-and-prollygeek).